# Magento css condition for !IE

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I try to include my css file like

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/style.css</name><params/><if>!IE</if></action>
```

To do a condition like

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<!--<![endif]-->
```

How can i do it? Or does it exist another method to include it only when it's not IE?

Thank you for your help! It's my first ever magento theme ^^

Answer (score 0):

Conditional comments are always rendered. They (and their contents') evaluation depends on the browser being <= IE9. There is no source conditional comment which works for all non-IE browsers. I suppose you could do something like this with JavaScript or PHP (relying on unreliable User-Agent) but by that point you have the wrong problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a bit messy but seems to work:

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/non-ie-stylesheet.css</name><params/><if>!IE]--></if></action>
```

Notice that I have done something special with the IF-condition:

```
<if>!IE]--></if>
```

Which outputs this:

```
<!--[if !IE]-->]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="[redacted]/css/non-ie-stylesheet.css" media="all" />
<![endif]-->
```

Like I said the markup it outputs isn't pretty and won't validate but all modern browsers seem to disregard that and IE ignores that stylesheet.